# how the presto shows partitions before presto execute hql？

Tags: hive, presto, trino

I used pyhive to connect hive to use Presto.

May I know the partitions of the hive tables before presto has executed the sql?

Comment: It is presto is wrapper so it is not not possibel..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 18):

You can use the below presto query to get partitions.

```
presto> select * from db_name."table_name$partitions";
p_regionkey 
-------------
       1 
       2 
       3
```

The result of SHOW PARTITIONS on hive is below.

```
hive> show partitions table_name;
p_regionkey=1
p_regionkey=2
p_regionkey=3
```

SHOW PARTITIONS on presto was removed on 0.209.
https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-0.209.html

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for

```
select "$path" from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the SHOW PARTITIONS command:
https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/0.167-t/sql/show-partitions.html
For example:
SHOW PARTITIONS FROM table_name;

Comment: Oddly there is no documentation of SHOW PARTITIONS in the official Presto docs - I replaced the 404ing link with one from Teradata, which for this case is the same generic Presto syntax.

Comment: SHOW PARTITIONS was removed in version 0.202 (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-0.202.html) in favor of the synthetic "<table>$partitions" tables. See the examples sections under https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html for how to do this now.